# How to indent multiple lines by single characters in Geany?

Tags: shortcut-keys, geany

Basically I'm looking for what is analogous to selecting a block of text or lines and hitting tab; but instead of tab doing so with the space-bar.

Is there an easy shortcut for it?  Can't find anything anywhere.  When I select a block of text, and hit the space-bar it replaces the lot with a single space!

Comment: Worked!  fantastic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@DK Bose](https://askubuntu.com/users/248158/dk-bose) said in his comment above...

1. Position the cursor directly in front of the first line which you
   are wanting to indent by 1 or more single character spaces.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and (in my case) press the down arrow to grow the
   cursor to how ever many lines you want (removing line wrapping
   helps!).  Basically you'll end up with a very long vertical cursor
   blinking.
3. Press <kbd>space</kbd>!  It will now move multiple lines at the same time by a
   single character spacing.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available in the [Extra Selection](https://plugins.geany.org/geanyextrasel.html) plugin, and could be unavailable depending on your installation.

It had a *Column mode* actionable with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> key combination (configurable).

Then, all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+*Movement keys* do rectangle selection instead of stream and your typing is on each lines simultaneously.

Comment: This is the default behavior on my config, you can set another key combo via _settings_ - _shortuts_

Answer (score 0):

Just select multiple lines you want to give space at once and hit TAB.
It will move all lines to forward in Pycharm